# Get a timestamp's monday's date

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

How do I get the previous Monday's date of a timestamp?  Basically a "week of" field.

I googled and got this for MS SQL but doesn't work for Postgresql.

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0) MondayOfCurrentWeek
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select date_trunc('week', current_timestamp)
```

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC